# How to exit from Kiosk mode?

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, kiosk

I configured ubuntu 16.04 in kiosk mode to open google chrome as said in this article
https://dej.in.ua/ubuntu-server-16-04-kiosk-mode/

Can any one explain How can i exit from kiosk mode? None of the Function keys are working to get a console. i tried Ctrl+Alt+T to fire up a terminal but its also not working in kiosk mode.

What is the solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

`Ctrl+Alt+F2`

This opens a terminal, if F2 pressed, on tty2.

Once you're done, press `Ctrl+Alt+F1` to switch back to the session on tty1. All you're doing with `Ctrl+Alt+F1/7` is switching between tty.

You can tell which tty you're on by running `$ w` in terminal. Abridged output:

```
USER     TTY 
kiosk    tty1
myuser   tty2
```

Comment: What if Ctrl+Alt+F2 doesn't work because other ttys don't get shown on the screen of this embedded computer? (the screen just freezes until Ctrl+Alt+F7 is pressed)