# Exit from kiosk mode

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, kiosk

Im running a wallmount scanner with Ubuntu 20.04 in kiosk mode and the system is set to auto load to a browser page using chrome. Everything works great as it loads directly to the page upon startup, but how do I exit out of it if I need to get to the desktop?

Comment: Does [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/953642/1222991) work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, its alt+f4. then once I restarted went back into Kiosk mode as it was supposed to.